# Typescript return mapped array from array of objects, where values are of types of passed property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have global util helper , which accepts array of objects and property (That property is keyof incoming object from array). The util function returnes mapped version with values from that objects and the value is determined by property.

```
type IShared = {
    ID: number,
};

export const getPropertiesArray = <T extends IShared>(data: T[], property: keyof T = 'ID'): Array<T[keyof T]> => {
    return data.map(item => item[property]).sort();
};
```

And let's imagine this is the array of objects

```
const data = [
    { ID: 1, name: 'test', secondName: 'testing', info: 'info' },
    { ID: 2, name: 'test2', secondName: 'testing2', info: 'info2' },
    { ID: 3, name: 'test3', secondName: 'testing3', info: 'info3' },
];

const resultArray = getPropertiesArray(data);
```

Typescript here creates type for *resultArray* as

> **(string | number | undefined)[]**

But the expected result is for example if `property` is *ID*, then `number[]`, if is *secondName*, then `string[]`

Comment: T is object in this case.